# How do I associate a schema with a connection in MySQL Workbench 6.2

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

MySQL newbie question: how do I associate a schema that I saved to a custom location with a connection in MySQL Workbench 6.2 ?

Here's what I did:

(1) clicked the + sign on the home page to create a new model
(2) right clicked the "myDB" icon and changed the name to "test_schema"
(3) clicked "add Table" and created a test table w 2 fields
(4) selected File...Save As...  C:/test_folder/TEST.mwb

So far so good.  But how do I actually use this schema with a connection?  The connection setup screen doesn't recognize the name "test_schema" and I don't see any inputs that would associate my physical store C:/test_folder/TEST.mwb with the connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose the "Model Overview" panel for ER model you have been developing. Double click the database icon ... the thing that looks like a yellowish barrel.

You'll be given a chance to change the name of the schema. Change it to what you want.

Then choose "Forward Engineer..." and follow the series of screens.

This will load tables for your schema into MySQL.

Once your schema is in the database, that's where your data will reside. The Workbench's design file doesn't contain your data, but only the design of your schema. You can think of it as a kind of source code, that needs to be compiled and loaded into the MySQL server to be useful.

If you need to move your schema and data to some other server, investigate the export and import function in the Workbench.

Comment: Thanks much  -  a little confusing but I got it to work with your hint.   Does the *.mwb file contain everything - i.e. schema and data and can it be moved and/or copied to other locations using windows copy functions ?

Comment: No, the .mwb file doesn't contain the data. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks again.  (And I found the data store hidden in C:\Program Data\MySql\etc...)  but obviously not designed for moving around.